# Grails with Intellij - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: spring, grails, intellij-idea

I am trying to run an existing Grails project within Intellij Idea. The project will run from the command line using `grails run-app`, however when I try to run the project from within Intellij I get the error 
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/filter/GenericFilterBean`

The GenericFilterBean class exists within the grails directory in the location C:\grails-2.4.3\lib\org.springframework\spring-web\jars, and I have additionally tried to add the Jar as a dependency of the module within the project structure (to ensure that it is included on the classpath).
I don't understand why the project will run from the command line but fails within Intellij.

I am using Grails version 2.4.3 and Java 1.8.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening?

```
2015-07-20 12:33:46,752 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: org/springframework/web/filter/GenericFilterBean
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/filter/GenericFilterBean
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.getLocked(LazyReference.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.get(LazyReference.java:33)
    at SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin$_closure2.doCall(SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin.groovy:209)
    at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.invokeBeanDefiningClosure(BeanBuilder.java:754)
    at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.beans(BeanBuilder.java:584)
    at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.invokeMethod(BeanBuilder.java:527)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 21 more
Error |
Forked Grails VM exited with error
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Make sure you synchronized your Grails settings with Idea (i.e. you run Grails/Synchronize Grails settings Idea command)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This worked for me, I had to delete the project and then clone it from Github again, but then once I synchronized the settings then everything was working. I hadn't seen this option within Intellij and this had been annoying me for days so thanks again

Comment: Same problem but didn't worked for me... :/